# Loading specific row takes longer than other rows with same value

Tags: cassandra

I'm retrieving a specific record from a fairly large column family. For this particular row key value, this takes significantly longer than for other rows *containing exactly the same columns/values*: almost 2 times longer.

The data is stored in a 2-node cluster with replication factor 2, and the times are measured after retrieving the rows a couple of times, to ensure that the data is cached by Cassandra.

What could be the reason for the exceptional retrieval time for this particular row? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: If using Cassandra 1.2 you should trace the request - in cqlsh you can do this by entering 'tracing on;' then running the query. One possibility is there are lots of tombstones in one row but not the others. The trace will tell you if this is true.

Comment: You were right, there were a lot of tombstones on it. Thanks!